# Using a InStr function within a Select Case

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

This does not seem to be working. Is there a way to do what I am trying to do here? I cant a case to be selected if the value is in a given sting:

```
Select Case gTTD.Cells(r, 4)

     Case InStr(gTTD.Cells(r, 4), "MASTER LOG")
         resp = "MM LOG"
      Case InStr(gTTD.Cells(r, 4), "MASTER MET")
         resp = "MM MET"
     Case "PIR"
         gTTD.Cells(r, 7) = "Martin TrÃ©panier"
         resp = "Martin TrÃ©panier"

 End Select
```

I understand why this cant work but is there a way of making it work? thank you

Thank you

Comment: I would use `If...Then...Else` for this case

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is a little trick I use, the select statement just wants to find results that are the same. Here is a simple example:

```
    Select Case True
        Case (1 = 2)
            Stop
        Case (2 = 3)
            Stop
        Case (4 = 4)
            Stop
        Case Else
            Stop
    End Select
```

This will fall into the 4=4 case.  In your example, this might be the simple answer:

```
Select Case True

     Case (InStr(gTTD.Cells(r, 4), "MASTER LOG") > 0)
         resp = "MM LOG"
      Case (InStr(gTTD.Cells(r, 4), "MASTER MET") > 0)
         resp = "MM MET"
     Case else
         gTTD.Cells(r, 7) = "Martin TrÃ©panier"
         resp = "Martin TrÃ©panier"
 End Select
```

Comment: ya this is nice! very interesting concept thatnks

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the `> -1`.  For me, using `InStr() > -1` will always return `True`, am I right?

Comment: Instr() gives the position of the first occurrence of one string within another. If it is not found, it will return -1. What this does is if the code within the parenthesis results in a true, it will fall into the case.

Comment: Sorry, I think VBA's INSTR() is 1 based which means not found results in a 0, not a -1. If so, this needs to be > 0. Might depend on the version of VBA (if I remember right)

Comment: Alright, thanks.  I was just checking if I had missed something.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445031(v=vs.60).aspx), `InStr()` returns 0 if searched string is not found.  I think you should edit your answer in order to disambiguate.

Comment: @simpLEMAn - Edited for VBA instead of VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
dim r as integer
for r = 1 to 'number of rows
    if Instr(gTTD.Cells(r, 4), "MASTER LOG") <> 0 then
         resp = "MM LOG"
    elseif Instr(gTTD.Cells(r, 4), "MASTER MET") <> 0 then
        resp = "MM MET"
    else
        gTTD.Cells(r, 7) = "Martin TrÃ©panier"
        resp = "Martin TrÃ©panier"
    end if
next r
```