# Find determined Shapes and change Color

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365

I have a document full of different shapes (almost 300). I'm trying to only change color of rectangles (almost 120), when a radial button is pressed. Can u guys help me?

My first thought was to use "select case" based on the name of the shape (which contain the word rectangles), but with no sucess.

Something like this:

```
Private Sub OptionButton4_Click ()
Dim sShapes as Shape

For Each sShapes In ActiveDocument.Shapes
Select Case sShapes.Name

Case InStr( , sShapes.Name, "Rectangle") = 1
sShapes.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(243, 43, 1)

Case InStr(1, sShapes.Name, "Retângulo") = 0
MsgBox "No"

End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: The variable name in the code in your question is inconsistent. You have used both `sShapes` and `sShape`. I would change it to `sShape` as this would be more logical. The name of the routine also looks a little odd, perhaps it should be `OptionButton4_Click`

Comment: Thanks for notice, those were transcription error when i was creating the post, on the document, is correct. I'm changing on the post now

Comment: To use case instr you need to do [Select Case True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887263/using-a-instr-function-within-a-select-case)

Comment: `For Each` requires `Next`. Why `Case` and why not simply `If ... End If`` Works perfectly ok.

Comment: Also using plural form when the object is a single one, is not nice for somebody else, that might need to read your sw. I refer to `sShapes` in `For Each sShapes In ...`. Better: `For Each sShape In ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the User Sgdva, i got it.

I'm using the following code.

```
Private Sub OptionButton4_Click()
Dim sShapes As Shape
For Each sShapes In ActiveDocument.Shapes

Select Case True

Case InStr(sShapes.Name, "Rectangle")
sShapes.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(243, 43, 1)

Case Else

End Select

Next sShapes

End Sub
```